# write antialiased text with custom font on transparent image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, wand, pycairo

so, as the topic says, I want to write some text on an transparent image.
Or, to be more specific, I want to write on multiple specific positions different text. The point is, I want to use a custom font (coolvetica) and (and there is my problem) I want it to be anti-aliased. unfortunately, PIL does not support font-anti-aliasing, as you might already know, but also see here:
[PIL example image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iOcC.png)
So as you see, PIL has not only an issue with the coordinates, but also does not really support font-anti-aliasing and adds some irritating black-ish border to the text. It is not very usable for me.
So after some searching, I found [Python Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.1/). The output is a lot better, but the antialiasing leads not to the result I want: [Wand example image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu75I.png) The curves are not as smooth as I want and there are some weird "pimples" like the dot at the end of the "r".
My code to use wand is this:

```
with Drawing() as draw:
    with wandimage(filename="Skispringen_Score.png") as img:
        draw.font_family = 'coolvetica.ttf'
        draw.text_antialias = True
        draw.fill_color = (Color("rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)"))
        for postionName, scorePosition in scoreContent.items():
            if isinstance(currentScoreText[postionName], int) and currentScoreText[postionName] > 9:
                center = 2
            else:
                center = 0

            draw.font_size = fontsize[scorePosition["size"]]
            draw.text(scorePosition["x"] - center, scorePosition["y"], str(currentScoreText[postionName]))
            draw(img)
        img.save(filename='wand-image.png')
```

And here is an example of what the text should actually look like: [PHP example image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7xy9.png)
This image was generated with php and the text looks as smooth as I want to.
I also tried to use cairo, but the documentation is really not that good (especially examples are rare) and I just don't even know how to write any text with it nor how to set an custom font.

The actual output image has an resolution of 1280x720 and is - besides of the text - completely transparent, the image is just an overlay for an videostream.

Do you have any idea how to get a nice looking text onto the image with python?

Answer (score 1):

You could try pycairo. Here are some code examples https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo/tree/master/examples

The reference docs for cairo are for C.

If you want even better results then you could render the image at 4 times the size and 
downsample it to the desired size.

You can also try some filters like a gaussian blur.

For pixel perfect images you will have to use the same rendering engine that your php function is using.